# Questions with no answers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, unanswered-questions, abandonment

Out of 3600 questions, it looks like just under 10% have no answer at all. This is just above the bar for a healthy beta site - has anyone analyzed the questions to see if there's any way to reduce the % of entirely unanswered questions?

Answer (score 5):

We have a new process that automatically removes very old, unloved unanswered questions network wide.

[Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

The actual criteria are:

- less than (question age in days * 1.5) views
- 0 score or lower
- no answers
- 1 comment or less
- asked more than 1 year ago

So, wait for these questions to get 365 days old and they should "die off" naturally.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/our-first-area-51-site-goes-public/

This site was in beta on June 30th 2010 -- so by June 30th 2011 we should start seeing auto-deletion of these sorts of questions.